Why won't this spray bottle spray?
50 years on this Earth yet I still have yet to find a single spray bottle that just works.  I have spent money on cheap and expensive ones and they either don't perform or last.  This is the latest iteration and I am flummoxed at how this thing even works.  Does anyone know how this works, how to fix it, or why it is broken? What is the point of the ball bearing?!
I have attempted to put my finger over the nozzle why pumping. I have tried an empty bottle and a full bottle.  I have also tried a filled bottle upside down without the inside tube extension.  I also tried pouring some olive oil into the water intake.



Does anyone know how this works, how to fix it, or why it is broken? ... this is a yes/no question that has a yes answer

it's a piston pump ... https://youtu.be/H5Kg-RzKSjM?si=h6WHE1B7ibsSJcRd

here's one with ball bearing valves ... https://youtu.be/tEDwKuIfFIA?si=5-AVObWdeWYKkTEI

Go to a florist and buy one of theirs - known to last ages...

It's you.  I have never had a problem witha spray bottle

@EvilElf did you put chlorine bleach  into the bottle?

@jsotola I have not.  I have in the past and figured that might be the culprit so I made sure not to this time.  Just water and some dishwashing soap.

I agree mine die within 1 year or less. I assume cheap plastic degrades and cracks, losing a seal somewhere, but I have never bothered to find out where - I just wastefully buy another cheap one.  I assume the Isopropanol or soap I put in there eventually degrades the plastic.
